# MockMvc uses wrong ApplicationContext when it is used in a nested class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

Apparently Spring creates another `ApplicationContext` when a `@Nested` class has custom configuration, e.g. `@TestPropertySource`. In that case two application contexts exist, one `AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext` as usual and another one used in the scope of the nested class with the type of `GenericWebApplicationContext`.

The problem is, when a `MockMvc` variable is defined and autowired at the base class level, i.e. outside of the nested class, but then used in the nested class, this variable will "use" the `ApplicationContext` of the base class.

My solution is to simply define and autowire a `MockMvc` variable in the nested class as well, however it took me some time to understand the issue and I wanted to make sure that I'm not missing something and using a wrong approach.

Here is an example

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class DemoControllerTests
{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Nested
    class NestedClassWithoutCustomConfiguration
    {
        // works as expected; mockMvc and nested class use same application context of type
        // "AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext"
    }

    @Nested
    @TestPropertySource(properties = "foo=bar")
    class NestedClassWithCustomConfiguration
    {
        // does not work as expected; a new applicationContext of type "GenericWebApplicationContext" is created;
        // however mockMvc is using "base" applicationContext of type "AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext"
    }
}
```